# Batch file to insert line into open window

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm sure this is possible to do, I'm just not 100% sure how.
I host a dedicated server for Don't Starve Together (DST) on my personal computer, I use a single .bat file to start it up:

```
h:\steamcmd\steamcmd.exe +login anonymous +app_update 343050 validate +quit
cd /D "h:\steamcmd\steamapps\common\Don't Starve Together Dedicated Server\bin"
start dontstarve_dedicated_server_nullrenderer -console -cluster CarnageServer -shard Master
start dontstarve_dedicated_server_nullrenderer -console -cluster CarnageServer -shard Caves
```

It basically starts 2 connected servers (Master & Caves) and has them both as open CMD windows on my desktop.
This all runs fine etc. no issues.

But when I close my computer down I have to use a command "c_shutdown(true)" in both windows to close and save each server. (I can't just close the windows, it will not make a save)
As the CMD windows are quite active, it makes it very hard to type out anything in them.

**My question is; is there a way to make a .bat file that can insert the line "c_shutdown(true)" into each window to execute the command?**

Then I can basically just leave a shortcut to it on my desktop and double click it to save and close down the server fully without much hassle.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: try with [sendkeys.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/sendKeys.bat)  - `call sendkeys.bat "server_console_title" "c_shutdown(true)"`  - it should be executed in a separate cmd session.

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely on the title in the title bar.  Assuming the title is Master and Cave, you could do something like

```
@setlocal
@set script="%temp%\exit.js"
@echo var oShell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell') > %script%
@echo oShell.AppActivate(WScript.arguments(0)) >> %script%
@echo oShell.SendKeys('c_shutdown(true)\r') >> %script%

@cscript //NoLogo %script% Master
@cscript //NoLogo %script% Cave
@del %script%
@endlocal
```

I prefer using @ to echo off - you can remove it on the lines you wish to watch instead of watching all the lines as they execute